# Bash: get a list of container names from docker-compose.yml

Tags: bash, shell, docker, docker-compose

I have my containers scattered into multiple `docker-compose.yml` files (https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/). They are separated based on the project, but a few containers are common to all projects. I have a neat shell script which lets me easily start a few projects at a time:

```
./myscript.sh up project1 project2
```

This executes:

```
docker-compose up -d -f shared/docker-compose.yml -f project1/docker-compose.yml -f project2/docker-compose.yml project1 project2
```

This starts the containers `project1`, `project2` & a few that are defined in the shared compose file, e.g. `shared-db`, `shared-apache`.

I now want to add to my shell script the option to kill the containers:

```
./myscript.sh kill
```

Should execute:

```
docker kill project1 project2 shared-db shared-apache
```

The problem is getting the list of my containers. My current approach is to use `docker ps --format '{{.Names}}'`, which isn't ideal as it can list also containers that are not a part of these projects.

I've also tried using `docker-compose kill`, which needs to be executed for each `docker-compose.yml` file separately. I looped through all the files and it worked for the first one, but  threw an error for the second:

```
ERROR: Service 'project1' depends on service 'shared-db' which is undefined.
```

The error is thrown because `project1/docker-compose.yml` has dependencies from `shared/docker-compose.yml` and they are unmet because `shared` was already killed.

The only way that comes to mind is somehow go through all the `docker-compose.yml` files and get a list of all the container names that are defined there, but I didn't find any proper way to parse `yml` files in bash.

```
services:
  db:
    image: ...
    container_name: shared-db

  apache:
    image: ...
    container_name: shared-apache
```

From the above `yml`, I'd have to get the names `shared-db` and `shared-apache`.

Comment: just `docker-compose down` then?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with docker-compose YAML files, but wouldn't `grep container_name: */docker-compose.yml | awk '{ print $2 }'` do the trick?

Comment: @KamilCuk `docker-compose down` has the same problem as `docker-compose kill`. @root thank you for the tip - although it didn't work properly, it brought me to the right solution (see my posted answer)

Comment: Why can't you `docker-compose -f shared/docker-compose.yml -f project1/docker-compose.yml -f project2/docker-compose.yml kill project1 project2`? Are you sure that it `needs to be executed for each docker-compose.yml file separately`?

Comment: @KamilCuk You're right. I went through what I've done yesterday and made the mistake of setting the `-f` option after the `kill` command. That returned the usage description and it didn't mention that I can use `-f` and so I've mistakenly thought that it doesn't work this way with `kill`. The nice thing is that you don't event need to specify the containers after `kill`. Works like a charm. Please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `docker-compose kill`:

```
docker-compose -f shared/docker-compose.yml -f project1/docker-compose.yml -f project2/docker-compose.yml kill
```

The option `-f` should come before the command to `docker-compose`, that way it will be parsed as include files. You can use all possible `docker-compose` commands that way.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you are happy with `myscript.sh kill` killing *any* container started with `docker-compose`, you can use the labels that `docker-compose` applies to containers to identify targets.

To find all containers started using `docker-compose`:

```
docker ps --filter 'label=com.docker.compose.project'
```

So you could do something as simple as:

```
docker ps --filter 'label=com.docker.compose.project' -q |
xargs docker kill
```

---

See the `docker ps` documenation on [filtering](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#filtering) for more information.

Comment: Another option is to have the docker-compose YAML file label all containers with something that the script can find.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep container_name: */docker-compose.yml | awk '{print $3}'
```

or:

```
grep container_name: */docker-compose.yml | sed 's/^.*: //'
```